# SQL 2 INNER JOINS with 3 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access, inner-join

I've a question about a SQL query.. I'm building a prototype webshop in ASP.NET Visual Studio. Now I'm looking for a solution to view my products. I've build a database in MS Access, it consists of multiple tables.

The tables which are important for my question are:

- Product
- Productfoto
- Foto

[Below you'll see the relations between the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMbfT.png)

For me it is important to get three datatypes: Product title, price and image.
The product title, and the price are in the `Product` table. The images are in the `Foto` table.

Because a product can have more than one picture, there is a N - M relation between them. So I've to split it up, I did it in the `Productfoto` table.

So the connection between them is:

```
product.artikelnummer -> productfoto.artikelnummer 
productfoto.foto_id -> foto.foto_id
```

Then I can read the filename (in the database: `foto.bestandnaam`)

I've created the first inner join, and tested it in Access, this works:

```
SELECT titel, prijs, foto_id
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Productfoto
ON product.artikelnummer = productfoto.artikelnummer
```

But I need another `INNER JOIN`, how could I create that? I guess something like this (this one will give me an error)

```
SELECT titel, prijs, bestandnaam
FROM Product 
(( INNER JOIN Productfoto ON product.artikelnummer = productfoto.artikkelnummer )
INNER JOIN foto ON productfoto.foto_id = foto.foto_id)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: why do you use brackets?

Comment: If you remove the brackets your query is correct.

Comment: @stmnmn Brackets are necessary in MS Access when there is more than one join. Admittedly, the brackets are improperly placed, but they cannot be removed altogether. I do not understand the upvotes for these comments.

Answer (score 3):

something like this should work:

```
SELECT Product.titel, Product.prijs, Foto.bestandnaam FROM Product INNER JOIN
(Foto INNER JOIN Productfoto ON Foto.[foto_id] = Productfoto.[foto_id]) ON
Product.[artikelnummer] = Productfoto.[artikelnummer];
```

Comment: did u just copy my answer ? because i dont know if all the attribute names are correct.. did you try to remove the brackets in your own query ? that really should work.

Comment: @JelmerHoltes `operator not...` *what?* Please post the entire message and don't trim it yourself.

Comment: Another solution I've tested is:

> SELECT titel,prijs, bestandnaam
FROM Product, Productfoto, Foto
WHERE product.artikelnummer = productfoto.artikelnummer 
AND productfoto.foto_id = foto.foto_id

But this query has two problems:

 - When a product has multiple images, I'll only show one of them, so I must limit it to one, but how? Else, I get three times the same product with a different image. 
 - When a product doesn't have a image, it isn't visible..

![Attachment, the "Acqua di Gio homme 100 ml...." displays 3 times][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CTMze.png

Comment: @JaneDoe My Microsoft Access is Dutch, it says: "Syntaxisfout (operator ontbreekt) in query-expressie product.artikkelnummer = productfoto.artikelnummer inner join foto on foto.foto_id = productfoto.foto_i."

Comment: have you tried building the query through the access query builder wizard? you can just add the 3 tables you need and access will automatically generate the query for you. I don't see what wrong with the query you've posted, must be something specific in access. edit: this is a longshot: but try to remove the spaces before and after the "=" operator

Comment: @JaneDoe Yes! I've used the wizard (it doesn't work until this moment), it created this query: SELECT Product.titel, Product.prijs, Foto.bestandnaam
FROM Product INNER JOIN (Foto INNER JOIN Productfoto ON Foto.[foto_id] = Productfoto.[foto_id]) ON Product.[artikelnummer] = Productfoto.[artikelnummer];

And now it works! But.. one problem: I would like to show only one image per product, how could I do that?

Comment: if i read your question correctly, i assume that 1 product can have more than 1 image? not sure how you could do that, but you can try to use the DISTINCT keyword. something like select DISTINCT(product.titel...) etc

Comment: That's correctly, a product can have multiple images. I've 44 products, but the query results 53 results. So there are some duplicates. I've tested GROUP BY and DISTINCT but it will not work for me with a query like this:

SELECT DISTINCT (product.artikelnummer), titel, prijs, bestandnaam
FROM Product INNER JOIN (Foto INNER JOIN Productfoto ON Foto.[foto_id] = Productfoto.[foto_id]) ON Product.[artikelnummer] = Productfoto.[artikelnummer];

Comment: @Jelmer, what are you expecting to get? If some products have multiple pictures, you will get a row for that product for each of the pictures.

Comment: @Jelmer, your Syntaxfout was probably caused by a typo: `product.artikkelnummer` has a 'k' too many...

Comment: You cannot have two inner joins in MS Access without including brackets. Access is very fussy about this. Please correct your query to show MS Access SQL.

Comment: @JaneDoe Thank you. I took the liberty of adding the missing square bracket :)

Answer (score 1):

**One thing about the use of linking tables**

The ProductFoto table allows for N-M relations between Product and Foto indeed. Is this what you really want/need? In other words, can one Foto belong to more than one Product? If not, put the Product_Id on the Foto table. If so,...

**...let's discuss JOIN.**

Say we have two tables, A and B. doing a

```
SELECT * FROM A, B
```

will give you all permutations of A's rows with B's rows. We could limit the resultset by adding a `WHERE` clause, like `WHERE A.a='lekker hoor!'`, or a way cooler `WHERE A.id=B.a_id`. Which actually starts to look like a `JOIN` result!

Lets do a proper `JOIN` then:

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.id=B.a_id
```

`JOIN`s actually come in `LEFT OUTER`, `RIGHT OUTER` and `FULL INNER` or `FULL OUTER` joins.

- A `LEFT JOIN` (use of `OUTER` is optional) will contain all records in the left (first) table, even if there is no corresponding records(s) in the right (second) table.
- A `RIGHT JOIN` obviously works the same way, but mirrored.
- With a `FULL OUTER JOIN` both tables are optional (not quite the same as `SELECT * FROM A, B` though!).
- A `FULL INNER` needs matching records from both tables (this is the default).

When you do want to do more than one `JOIN`, say

```
SELECT * FROM 
  A 
  JOIN B ON A.id=B.a_id
  JOIN C ON B.id=C.b_id
```

You can think of the extra `JOIN` as joining on an intermediate table, formed by joining A and B, especially when mixing some `LEFT`/`RIGHT`/`INNER`/`OUTER` `JOIN`s.

---

**As to your question**
Use something along the lines of

```
SELECT TOP (1) titel, prijs, bestandnaam
FROM 
( -- this bracket is MS Access specific (and awkward)
  Product 
  INNER JOIN Productfoto ON product.artikelnummer = productfoto.artikelnummer
) -- this one too
  INNER JOIN foto ON productfoto.foto_id = foto.foto_id
```

- to satisfy MS Access, use brackets around first two tables, see [Ms-Access: Join 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901935/ms-access-join-3-tables)
- Normally no brackets required (you'll get to use them like this when you discover sexy sub-selects, for which the rule is: only use them if there is no alternative).
- Because there are multiple matches in your ProductFoto table, there are multiple matches in your result. Use TOP 1 (or LIMIT 1, depending on your DB) to 'fix' this.

Veel success, en doe jezelf een plezier en *switch to English*!

Comment: you made the same mistake, "artiKKel" :P

Comment: The tags say MS Access. You cannot run that in MS Access, it will fail.

Comment: @Remou why will it fail, and what would work in that (abomination of a) database?

Comment: You cannot have two joins without brackets. MS Access is very fussy about this (see also my comment above).