# Joining 3 Tables In SQL and Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset

[image: Program]

[image: Database]

```
    Public Class frmSelect

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT tblStudInfo.LastName AS myName, tblAddress.Address AS myAddress, tblCourses.CourseName AS myCourse FROM tblStudInfo INNER JOIN tblAddress ON tblStudInfo.AddressID = tblAddress.AddressID INNER JOIN tblCourses ON tblStudInfo.CourseCode = tblCourses.CourseCode WHERE tblStudInfo.StudID = '01-2016-003'", mConnection.myConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "tblStudInfo")

        Me.TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("tblStudInfo").Rows(0)("myName").ToString
        Me.TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables("tblStudInfo").Rows(0)("myAddress").ToString
        Me.TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables("tblStudInfo").Rows(0)("myCourse").ToString

    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm using Visual Basic... I have 3 tables in the Database. I am trying to join 3 tables and pass it to my Dataset named ds. But I got a Syntax Error with the SQL command I have provided. I got no error on joining 2 tables, but when I tried joining 3 tables with the code I have provided above, it is no longer working.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: If you're using MS Access, extra parentheses are needed for the second join.

Comment: Syntax Error on SQL

Comment: @jarlh. How Sir? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also what type is the tblsStudInfo.StudID in the database??

Comment: @Kostis I am getting Syntax Error in SQL... tblStudInfo.StudID is Short Text.

Comment: @Kostis. My code was working when I was trying to join 2 tables... I got the error when I tried to join three tables.

Comment: Then you may need the extra parentheses as @jarlh mentioned.

Comment: @Kostis, what would be the syntax Sir?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ms-Access: Join 3 Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901935/ms-access-join-3-tables)

Comment: Have a look at the answers in that link @aer. They may help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367565/access-sql-inner-join-with-multiple-tables

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 2 joins work and not 3, and that your SQL statement is syntaxically correct, I suspect that your backend DB is MS access. If it is the case, you should surround your JOINs with parenthesis :

```
SELECT tblStudInfo.LastName AS myName, tblAddress.Address AS myAddress, tblCourses.CourseName AS myCourse 
FROM ((tblStudInfo 
INNER JOIN tblAddress ON tblStudInfo.AddressID = tblAddress.AddressID )
INNER JOIN tblCourses ON tblStudInfo.CourseCode = tblCourses.CourseCode) 
WHERE tblStudInfo.StudID = '01-2016-003'
```